# Multiple or Hierarchical regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, spss

I'm currently doing research on parent/child feeding and using 2 questionnaires to predict the score of the 3rd questionnaire. However, I have a lot of other predictor variables:

- gender
- age
- ethnicity
- education
- child's age
- child's gender
- score of questionnaire 1
- subscale of questionnaire 2
- subscale of questionnaire 2

I'm unsure which method to do as each predictor variable has a body of research for its significance, but the majority are also just demographic, whilst 9 individual predictors seems like a large amount. my current sample is also around 120 people.

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The key question here is whether you expect different questionnaire scores for the same parent/child to be correlated, even after you've adjusted for gender, age, etc. I assume that you do.

Comment: @DoctorMilt from my initial analyses the two questionnaires and subscales don't seem to be particularly correlated (.253)